# Custom Tuplizer in Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, tuplizer

We're trying to pull off  [this spectaular hack](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2011/01/28/how-to-use-0-instead-of-null-for-foreign-keys.aspx), and have got as far as

```
foreach (var persistentClass in configuration.ClassMappings)
{
    persistentClass.AddTuplizer(EntityMode.Poco, typeof(NullableTuplizer).AssemblyQualifiedName);
}
```

but have no idea where this loop should go given we're using fluent NHibernate. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(...)
    .Mappings(...)
    .ExposeConfiguration(config =>
    {
        foreach (var persistentClass in config.ClassMappings)
        {
            persistentClass.AddTuplizer(EntityMode.Poco, typeof(NullableTuplizer).AssemblyQualifiedName);
        }
    })
```