# How to add a custom tuplizer for a Component programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, tuplizer

Can anyone give me some direction as to how to add a custom tuplizer for a Component programmatically?

To add it to a class is as simple as:

```
new Configuration().ClassMappings
                   .First()
                   .AddTuplizer(EntityMode.Map, "tuplizerClassName");
```

But how do you accomplish the same thing for Components?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Tuplizer in Fluent Nhibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920592/custom-tuplizer-in-fluent-nhibernate)

Comment: @Inuyasha, Not a duplicate. A Component tuplizer is not a Class tuplizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
config.ClassMappings
    .SelectMany(cm => cm.PropertyIterator)
    .Where(prop => prop.IsComposite)
    .Select(prop => prop.Value)
    .Cast<NHibernate.Mapping.Component>()
    .ForEach(c => c.TuplizerMap[NHibernate.EntityMode.Map] = "tuplizerClassName");
```

Comment: I landed in something similar. Thanks!